# Change values dependent on Object

Tags: geometry-nodes

is there a possibility to say: if the object choosen by my input is "X", then use this group of nodes. But if it is "Y" use the other group?

Because I want to use this my setup to speed up my planning process and I have to use different object depending on the project.

I hope my explanation makes sense :)

Blend file: https://we.tl/t-zt1axfrEhF

[image: Node Setup]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It has a Greater Than/Less Than option in the math node.

Comment: SO how could i compare the names or objects themselves? Because the node only takes mathematical values and not strings or objects

Comment: It is not possible to do that kind of filtering. If both objects have a different number of vertices you can try filtering with that

Comment: Hey @Gorgious thanks for the hint, it worked. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Today, you cannot get object name as string in geometry-nodes.

But, if your two object have different number of vertices, first get the object vertices amount, for example 8, and then the node setup:

[image]

### You also can do a switch

[image]